# Coffeescript + three.js: scene undefined

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, three.js

I'm trying to find out the error for some hours and nothing comes to my mind...

I get this error:

```
Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
```

Here's my coffeescript file: (hope it's readable)(main function at the end) (I've pointed where error occurs)

```
class _3D_Engine_
constructor: () ->
    # define all neccessary constants
    @STATS_ENABLED = true
    @divBackgroundColor = '#D7F0F7'
    @cameraInitPos = new THREE.Vector3(10, 10, 10)
    @cameraLookAtObject = null
    @cameraFov = 45
    @cameraNear = 1
    @cameraFar = 4800
    @rendererSize = new THREE.Vector2(Math.min(window.innerWidth, 1440), (5 / 8 * window.innerHeight))
    @controlsMovementSpeed = 100
    @controlsLookSpeed = 0.1
    @skyBoxSize = new THREE.Vector3(4500, 2000, 4500)
    @floorSize = new THREE.Vector2(4500, 4500)
    @floorColor = 0x9FB98A
    @lightColor = 0xFFFFFF
    @lightIntensity = 0.8
    @lightInitPos = new THREE.Vector3(-2500, 2000, 2500)
    @fogColor = 0xFFFFFF
    @fogMinDist = 200
    @fogMaxDist = 6000
    @shadowCameraVisible = false
    @shadowDarkness = 0.3
    @shadowMap = new THREE.Vector2(4000, 4000)
    @shadowCameraFar = 5500
    @shadowCameraLRTB = new THREE.Vector4(-3000, 3000, 3000, -3000)

    # the most important variables
    @scene = null
    @camera = null
    @renderer = null
    @light = null
    @clock = null
    @constrols = null

    # models loaded
    @streetsLoaded = false
    @buildingsLoaded = false

setUpWorld: () ->
    if @sceneLoaded() is false
        @setUpScene() # create scene, download all 3D models
    if @sceneLoaded() is true
        @setUpCamera() # set up all cameras
        @setUpRenderer() # set up renderer
        @setUpClock() # activating clock
        @setUpControls() # set up FirstPersonControls
        @setUpStats() # set up statistics
        @setUpLights() # set up light
        @setUpShadows() # set up shadows
        @setUpFog() # set up fog
        $("#loading").hide()
        document.body.appendChild(@renderer.domElement)
        document.body.appendChild(@stats.domElement)
        @animate()

setUpScene: () ->
    if @streetsLoaded is false and @buildingsLoaded is false
        @scene = new THREE.Scene()
        @cameraLookAtObject = @scene.position
        @setUpSkyBox() # set up sky
        @setUpFloor() # set up ground
        @streetsLoaded = true
        @buildingsLoaded = true
        @setUpStreets('dae') # load streets.dae
    if @streetsLoaded is true and @buildingsLoaded is false
        @setUpBuildings('obj') # load buildings.obj + buildings.mtl

setUpCamera: () ->
    @camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(@cameraFov, @rendererSize.x / @rendererSize.y, @cameraNear, @cameraFar)
    @camera.position.set(@cameraInitPos.x, @cameraInitPos.y, @cameraInitPos.z)
    @camera.lookAt(@cameraLookAtObject)

setUpRenderer: () ->
    @renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true})
    @renderer.setSize(@rendererSize.x, @rendererSize.y)
    @renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true

setUpClock: () ->
    @clock = new THREE.Clock()

setUpControls: () ->
    @controls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls(@camera)
    @controls.movementSpeed = @controlsMovementSpeed
    @controls.lookSpeed = @controlsLookSpeed

setUpStats: () ->
    if @STATS_ENABLED is true
        @stats = new Stats()
        @stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute'
        @stats.domElement.style.top = '0px'
        @stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 100
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#D7F0F7'

setUpLights: () ->
    @light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(@lightColor, @lightIntensity)
    @light.position.set(@lightInitPos.x, @lightInitPos.y, @lightInitPos.z)
    @scene.add(@light)
    # Lights created
    $("#lights-text").text("Creating lights... 100.00%")

setUpShadows: () ->
    @light.castShadow = true
    @light.shadowDarkness = @shadowDarkness
    @light.shadowMapWidth = @shadowMap.x
    @light.shadowMapHeight = @shadowMap.y
    @light.shadowCameraFar = @shadowCameraFar
    @light.shadowCameraLeft = @shadowCameraLRTB.x
    @light.shadowCameraRight = @shadowCameraLRTB.y
    @light.shadowCameraTop = @shadowCameraLRTB.z
    @light.shadowCameraBottom = @shadowCameraLRTB.w
    if @shadowCameraVisible is true
        @light.shadowCameraVisible = true
    # Shadows created
    $("#shadows-text").text("Creating shadows... 100.00%")

setUpFog: () ->
    @scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(@fogColor, @fogMinDist, @fogMaxDist )

setUpSkyBox: () ->
    materials = [
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/coffee/textures/skybox/px.jpg') } )
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/coffee/textures/skybox/nx.jpg') } )
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/coffee/textures/skybox/py.jpg') } )
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/coffee/textures/skybox/ny.jpg') } )
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/coffee/textures/skybox/pz.jpg') } )
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/coffee/textures/skybox/nz.jpg') } )
    ]
    @skybox = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.BoxGeometry(@skyBoxSize, @skyBoxSize, @skyBoxSize),
        new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials)
    )
    @skybox.scale.x = - 1;
    @skybox.position.y = -3000
    @scene.add(@skybox)

setUpFloor: () ->
    @floor = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.PlaneGeometry(@floorSize, @floorSize),
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            color: @floorColor
            overdraw: true
        })
    )
    @floor.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI
    @floor.position.y = -0.1
    @floor.receiveShadow = true
    @scene.add(@floor)

setUpStreets: (format) ->
    if format is 'obj'
        (new THREE.OBJMTLLoader()).load('/coffee/models/obj/streets/streets.obj', '/coffee/models/obj/streets/streets.mtl', ( object ) ->
            object.recieveShadow = true
            object.traverse( ( node ) ->
                if node instanceof THREE.Mesh
                    node.receiveShadow = true
            )
            @scene.add(object)
            @streetsLoaded = true
            # Loading streets completed - change picture
            $("#loading-streets").text("Loading streets... 100.00%")
            @setUpScene() # continue set up scene
        )
    else if format is 'dae'
        (new THREE.ColladaLoader()).load('/coffee/models/dae/streets/streets.dae', (result) ->
            object = result.scene
            object.recieveShadow = true
            object.traverse( ( node ) ->
                if node instanceof THREE.Mesh
                    node.receiveShadow = true
            )
            @scene.add(object) # <-------------------- (error here) <---------------
            @streetsLoaded = true
            # Loading streets completed - change picture
            $("#loading-streets").text("Loading streets... 100.00%")
            @setUpScene() # continue set up scene
        )

setUpBuildings: (format) ->
    if format is 'obj'
        (new THREE.OBJMTLLoader()).load('/coffee/models/obj/buildings/buildings.obj', '/coffee/models/obj/buildings/buildings.mtl', (object) ->
            object.receiveShadow = true
            object.castShadow = true
            object.traverse( ( node ) ->
                if node instanceof THREE.Mesh
                    node.castShadow = true
                    node.receiveShadow = true
            )
            @scene.add(object)
            @buildingsLoaded = true
            # Loading buildings completed - change picture
            $("#loading-buildings").text("Loading buildings... 100.00%")
            @setUpWorld() # continue set up scene
        )
    else if format is 'dae'
        (new THREE.ColladaLoader()).load('/coffee/models/dae/buildings/buildings.dae', (result) ->
            object = result.scene
            object.receiveShadow = true
            object.castShadow = true
            object.traverse( ( node ) ->
                if node instanceof THREE.Mesh
                    node.castShadow = true
                    node.receiveShadow = true
            )
            @scene.add(object)
            @buildingsLoaded = true
            # Loading streets completed - change picture
            $("#loading-buildings").text("Loading buildings... 100.00%")
            @setUpWorld() # continue set up scene
        )

sceneLoaded: () ->
    return (@streetsLoaded is true and @buildingsLoaded is true)

animate: () ->
    @renderer.render(@scene, @camera)
    @stats.update()
    @controls.update(@clock.getDelta())
    requestAnimationFrame(@animate())


###################################################################        
########################## Start function #########################
###################################################################

@main = () ->
    @_3D_Engine = new _3D_Engine_()
    @_3D_Engine.setUpWorld()
    @_3D_Engine.animate()
```

The same code compiled to javascript:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.7.1
(function() {
  var _3D_Engine_;

  _3D_Engine_ = (function() {
    function _3D_Engine_() {
      this.STATS_ENABLED = true;
      this.divBackgroundColor = '#D7F0F7';
      this.cameraInitPos = new THREE.Vector3(10, 10, 10);
      this.cameraLookAtObject = null;
      this.cameraFov = 45;
      this.cameraNear = 1;
      this.cameraFar = 4800;
      this.rendererSize = new THREE.Vector2(Math.min(window.innerWidth, 1440), 5 / 8 * window.innerHeight);
      this.controlsMovementSpeed = 100;
      this.controlsLookSpeed = 0.1;
      this.skyBoxSize = new THREE.Vector3(4500, 2000, 4500);
      this.floorSize = new THREE.Vector2(4500, 4500);
      this.floorColor = 0x9FB98A;
      this.lightColor = 0xFFFFFF;
      this.lightIntensity = 0.8;
      this.lightInitPos = new THREE.Vector3(-2500, 2000, 2500);
      this.fogColor = 0xFFFFFF;
      this.fogMinDist = 200;
      this.fogMaxDist = 6000;
      this.shadowCameraVisible = false;
      this.shadowDarkness = 0.3;
      this.shadowMap = new THREE.Vector2(4000, 4000);
      this.shadowCameraFar = 5500;
      this.shadowCameraLRTB = new THREE.Vector4(-3000, 3000, 3000, -3000);
      this.scene = null;
      this.camera = null;
      this.renderer = null;
      this.light = null;
      this.clock = null;
      this.constrols = null;
      this.streetsLoaded = false;
      this.buildingsLoaded = false;
    }

    _3D_Engine_.prototype.setUpWorld = function() {
      if (this.sceneLoaded() === false) {
        this.setUpScene();
      }
      if (this.sceneLoaded() === true) {
        this.setUpCamera();
        this.setUpRenderer();
        this.setUpClock();
        this.setUpControls();
        this.setUpStats();
        this.setUpLights();
        this.setUpShadows();
        this.setUpFog();
        $("#loading").hide();
        document.body.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
        document.body.appendChild(this.stats.domElement);
        return this.animate();
      }
    };

    _3D_Engine_.prototype.setUpScene = function() {
      if (this.streetsLoaded === false && this.buildingsLoaded === false) {
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
        this.cameraLookAtObject = this.scene.position;
        this.setUpSkyBox();
        this.setUpFloor();
        this.streetsLoaded = true;
        this.buildingsLoaded = true;
        this.setUpStreets('dae');
      }
      if (this.streetsLoaded === true && this.buildingsLoaded === false) {
        return this.setUpBuildings('obj');
      }
    };

    _3D_Engine_.prototype.setUpCamera = function() {
      this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(this.cameraFov, this.rendererSize.x / this.rendererSize.y, this.cameraNear, this.cameraFar);
      this.camera.position.set(this.cameraInitPos.x, this.cameraInitPos.y, this.cameraInitPos.z);
      return this.camera.lookAt(this.cameraLookAtObject);
    };

    _3D_Engine_.prototype.setUpRenderer = function() {
      this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true
      });
      this.renderer.setSize(this.rendererSize.x, this.rendererSize.y);
      return this.renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
    };

    _3D_Engine_.prototype.setUpClock = function() {
      return this.clock = new THREE.Clock();
    };

    _3D_Engine_.prototype.setUpControls = function() {
      this.controls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls(this.camera);
      this.controls.movementSpeed = this.controlsMovementSpeed;
      return this.controls.lookSpeed = this.controlsLookSpeed;
    };

    _3D_Engine_.prototype.setUpStats = function() {
      if (this.STATS_ENABLED === true) {
        this.stats = new Stats();
        this.stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
        this.stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
        this.stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 100;
        return document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#D7F0F7';
      }
    };

    _3D_Engine_.prototype.setUpLights = function() {
      this.light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(this.lightColor, this.lightIntensity);
      this.light.position.set(this.lightInitPos.x, this.lightInitPos.y, this.lightInitPos.z);
      this.scene.add(this.light);
      return $("#lights-text").text("Creating lights... 100.00%");
    };

    _3D_Engine_.prototype.setUpShadows = function() {
      this.light.castShadow = true;
      this.light.shadowDarkness = this.shadowDarkness;
      this.light.shadowMapWidth = this.shadowMap.x;
      this.light.shadowMapHeight = this.shadowMap.y;
      this.light.shadowCameraFar = this.shadowCameraFar;
      this.light.shadowCameraLeft = this.shadowCameraLRTB.x;
      this.light.shadowCameraRight = this.shadowCameraLRTB.y;
      this.light.shadowCameraTop = this.shadowCameraLRTB.z;
      this.light.shadowCameraBottom = this.shadowCameraLRTB.w;
      if (this.shadowCameraVisible === true) {
        this.light.shadowCameraVisible = true;
      }
      return $("#shadows-text").text("Creating shadows... 100.00%");
    };

    _3D_Engine_.prototype.setUpFog = function() {
      return this.scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(this.fogColor, this.fogMinDist, this.fogMaxDist);
    };

    _3D_Engine_.prototype.setUpSkyBox = function() {
      var materials;
      materials = [
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/coffee/textures/skybox/px.jpg')
        }), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/coffee/textures/skybox/nx.jpg')
        }), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/coffee/textures/skybox/py.jpg')
        }), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/coffee/textures/skybox/ny.jpg')
        }), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/coffee/textures/skybox/pz.jpg')
        }), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/coffee/textures/skybox/nz.jpg')
        })
      ];
      this.skybox = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(this.skyBoxSize, this.skyBoxSize, this.skyBoxSize), new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
      this.skybox.scale.x = -1;
      this.skybox.position.y = -3000;
      return this.scene.add(this.skybox);
    };

    _3D_Engine_.prototype.setUpFloor = function() {
      this.floor = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(this.floorSize, this.floorSize), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: this.floorColor,
        overdraw: true
      }));
      this.floor.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI;
      this.floor.position.y = -0.1;
      this.floor.receiveShadow = true;
      return this.scene.add(this.floor);
    };

    _3D_Engine_.prototype.setUpStreets = function(format) {
      if (format === 'obj') {
        return (new THREE.OBJMTLLoader()).load('/coffee/models/obj/streets/streets.obj', '/coffee/models/obj/streets/streets.mtl', function(object) {
          object.recieveShadow = true;
          object.traverse(function(node) {
            if (node instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
              return node.receiveShadow = true;
            }
          });
          this.scene.add(object);
          this.streetsLoaded = true;
          $("#loading-streets").text("Loading streets... 100.00%");
          return this.setUpScene();
        });
      } else if (format === 'dae') {
        return (new THREE.ColladaLoader()).load('/coffee/models/dae/streets/streets.dae', function(result) {
          var object;
          object = result.scene;
          object.recieveShadow = true;
          object.traverse(function(node) {
            if (node instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
              return node.receiveShadow = true;
            }
          });
          this.scene.add(object); // <-------------------- (error here) <-------------
          this.streetsLoaded = true;
          $("#loading-streets").text("Loading streets... 100.00%");
          return this.setUpScene();
        });
      }
    };

    _3D_Engine_.prototype.setUpBuildings = function(format) {
      if (format === 'obj') {
        return (new THREE.OBJMTLLoader()).load('/coffee/models/obj/buildings/buildings.obj', '/coffee/models/obj/buildings/buildings.mtl', function(object) {
          object.receiveShadow = true;
          object.castShadow = true;
          object.traverse(function(node) {
            if (node instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
              node.castShadow = true;
              return node.receiveShadow = true;
            }
          });
          this.scene.add(object);
          this.buildingsLoaded = true;
          $("#loading-buildings").text("Loading buildings... 100.00%");
          return this.setUpWorld();
        });
      } else if (format === 'dae') {
        return (new THREE.ColladaLoader()).load('/coffee/models/dae/buildings/buildings.dae', function(result) {
          var object;
          object = result.scene;
          object.receiveShadow = true;
          object.castShadow = true;
          object.traverse(function(node) {
            if (node instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
              node.castShadow = true;
              return node.receiveShadow = true;
            }
          });
          this.scene.add(object);
          this.buildingsLoaded = true;
          $("#loading-buildings").text("Loading buildings... 100.00%");
          return this.setUpWorld();
        });
      }
    };

    _3D_Engine_.prototype.sceneLoaded = function() {
      return this.streetsLoaded === true && this.buildingsLoaded === true;
    };

    _3D_Engine_.prototype.animate = function() {
      this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
      this.stats.update();
      this.controls.update(this.clock.getDelta());
      return requestAnimationFrame(this.animate());
    };

    return _3D_Engine_;

  })();

  this.main = function() {
    this._3D_Engine = new _3D_Engine_();
    this._3D_Engine.setUpWorld();
    return this._3D_Engine.animate();
  };

}).call(this);
```

Comment: Why do you expect `@` (AKA `this`) to be anything particular in the callback? Have you looked at what `@` is in that callback? How about `@scene`?

Comment: I didn't fully understand your question... Butwhy it shouldn't be anything particular? I'm going through my code and before using this.scene I define it this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

Comment: But `this` in JavaScript depends on how a function is *called*, not where it is *defined* (baring bound functions of course). The documentation will tell you what `this` is going to be, if it doesn't then you can't depend on `this` being anything in particular. Maybe you want to define your callback with a [fat arrow (`=>`)](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow).

Comment: My mistake, forgot about it, but it's not working again... Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded (render _3D_Engine_.animate (anonymous function))

Comment: Then you have a hidden recursion problem (probably a callback that does something that triggers the callback to be called again). Check the stack trace and start debugging your code.

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame(@animate())` should be `requestAnimationFrame(@animate)`, but go learn why.

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I think that I sent not a function itself but the result of that function.

Comment: @EugeneKolesnikov If this issue is solved please, for future visitors, post a self-accepted answer in order to mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Changed '->' to '=>' and 'requestAnimationFrame(@animate())' to 'requestAnimationFrame(@animate)'